# Hidding a UITabBar and drawing in the space

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need to use the full screen-space on one of my views in my app.

So I hid the NavBar and hid the TabBar.

I could draw into the space left by the Navbar, but there is white space where the TabBar used to be.

I tried to set the self.view.frame to 480 height but it didnt seem to make any difference.

I'm guessing it not possible to get at this space? Or is there some trick i am missing.

Many Thanks,
Code

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the TabBar is intended to be hidden. After all, how would you get it back?
Can you use a modal view instead?